# react typescript map with useContext don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch, react-hooks

I try to fetch some data from the tvmaze api using react typescript and useContext, i can display the data but the useContext don't update with the return so when i use the map function nothing display any advice?

```
import React , { Fragment, useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Store from '../Store/Store'
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

export default function App() {

  const {state, dispatch} = useContext(Store)

  useEffect(() => {
    state.episodes.length === 0 && fetchDataAction()
  })

  const fetchDataAction = async () => {
    const URL = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=rick-&-morty&embed=episodes'
    const data = await fetch(URL);
    const dataJSON = await data.json();
    console.log(dataJSON._embedded.episodes);
    return dispatch({
      type: "FETCH-DATA",
      payload: dataJSON._embedded.episodes,
    })
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {console.log(state)}
      <h1>Rick and Morty</h1>
      <p>Pick your favorite episode!!!</p>
      <section>
        {state.episodes.map((episode: any) => {
          return (
            <section key={episode.id}>
              <img src={episode.image.medium} alt={`Rick and Morty ${episode.name}`} />
              <section>
                Season: {episode.season} Number: {episode.number}
              </section>
            </section>
          )
        })}
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

i'm not using redux but i'm using babel + webpack, i'm really new to all this so i'm a bit lost here my Store.tsx file,

```
 import React from 'react'

    interface IState {
      episodes: [],
      favorites: []
    }

    interface IAction {
      type: string,
      payload: any
    }

    const initialState:IState = {
      episodes: [],
      favorites: []
    };


    const Store = React.createContext<IState | any>(initialState)

    function reducer(state: IState, action: IAction): IState {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
          return { ...state, episodes: action.payload}
        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    export function StoreProvider(props: any): JSX.Element {
      const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
      return <Store.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>
    };

    export default Store;
```

Comment: what is your store code?

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: hi i'm not using redux i update the post and put my store code.

Comment: why do you have two export default in your App file?

Comment: oh sorry it's a post error the last is edited i don't use it

Comment: Where are you using your ```StoreProvider``` Component?

Comment: In my index.tsx :                                                                               
ReactDOM.render(
  <StoreProvider>
    <App />
  </StoreProvider>,
  document.getElementById("app-root")
);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213810/discussion-between-taghi-khavari-and-ganzo).

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo. you are dispatching type: "FETCH-DATA", and your swich statement is checking for case 'FETCH_DATA'.

To avoid this problem in the future, common practice is to create a separate file where you would declare actions, in your case "FETCH_CASE". you can do literally `const FETCH_ACTIONS = "FETCH_ACTIONS"`

And then in your files where your reducer and dispatcher are, you would import the action to make sure they are referring to the same thing.

1. redux and webpack/babel are not used for the same purpose - redux is for store management, similar to useContext. webpack and babel compile your code, more or less.
2. there is no need to import axios if you are not using it, you are using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for the same purpose you could use axios.
3. you have to declare fetchDataAction before you call it in the useEffect. in other words, useEffect should be below the function.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but it changes nothing my issue is the state dont update with the return dispatch at the end of fetchDataAction don't know why

Comment: when you write console.log(action.payload) right below  case 'FETCH_DATA' in your reducer, what do you get

Comment: like :     case 'FETCH_DATA':
      console.log(action.payload);
      return { ...state, episodes: action.payload}
    default:
      return state
  } ? that do nothing

Comment: that means that the dispatched action never reached the reducer, I have edited my answer